# Password_Bcrypt - PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um script em Shell que gera uma senha de forma randômica e salva em pass.txt.

Em php tenho o codigo abaixo, que abre este pass.txt, pega a senha que está nele e gera o Hash sobrescrevendo o pass.txt. Com este hash eu salvo no banco mysql:

```
    <?php
$senha1 = file_get_contents("/tmp/pass.txt");
#$senha1 = trim($senha1);
$senha1 = preg_replace('/s(?=s)/', '', $senha1);
$senha1 = preg_replace('/[nrt]/', ' ', $senha1);
$senha1 = preg_replace('/\\s\\s+/', ' ', $senha1);
$senha1 = password_hash($senha1, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, [cost => 12]);
$arquivo = "/tmp/pass.txt";
$fp = fopen($arquivo, "r+");
fwrite($fp, $senha1);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Porem, este processo é todo automatizado e as vezes o sistema loga e outras vezes não. Fiz o processo manual e neste momento nenhum acesso é permitido com o user e senha que é gerado. Não sei se neste processo, ao gerar o Hash, está sendo inserido algum lixo e etc. Mas usei o replace para testar remover residuos.

A unica situação "estranha" é que gera este Warning quando o php é executado:

```
PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant cost - assumed 'cost' (this will 
throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

Uso a função `password_verify` para validar a senha.

Através de alguns testes, setando a senha em uma variavel no proprio PHP e gerando o Hash através desta variavel funciona. Mas se a senha está em um TXT e pego a informação que está neste TXT e encripto a senha, não funciona.

Comment: O correto é `password_hash($senha1, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ["cost" => 12]);`

Comment: O Warning desapareceu. Obrigado. Mas executei o php na senha que criamos no pass.txt , é gerado o hash, jogo no mysql o hash e mesmo assim não acessa.